# Firefox 3.6 - btTooltip not working

Tags: firefox

```
/* Hide tooltips on toolbar bookmarks */
#btTooltip { display: none !important; }
```

I was using this CSS snipppet to suppress tooltips on bookmark toolbar items and it stopped working after FF 3.6

Is there a new CSS selector for this? I don't want to set config entry browser.chrome.toolbar_tips=false because that is too broad.

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the selector has been changed to bhTooltip instead of btTooltip! Wonder why, btTooltip implies "bookmark toolbar tooltip", not sure what bhTooltip means. Oh well, it works now.